# Android menu shared between activities (unwanted)

Tags: android, menu

I think I understood the Activity lifecycle on Android, but I still can't figure why the followin is happening.

- Login activity - Login screen
- Main activity - Main application interface

In Login activity, I connect to a service to validate the login. If the password is correct, I switch to Main activity using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

There is no Options menu in Login activity. 
I have an Options menu in Main activity that I inflate with:

```
    @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
     return true;
 }
```

So far so good. But I want the user to be able to log out and go back to login screen.
So in Main activity I have an option in the menu that allows logging out:

```
   @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle item selection
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.menuReset:
      getModel().deleteCredentials // stuff to logout from my service
      startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
      finish();
      return true;
     }
 }
```

If I press that menu button, the application displays Login activity again. But if I press the MENU key, the application displays the menu from Main activity even if it's not visible.

Furthermore, if I go back to home screen (pressing HOME) and come back to my activity after a while, the application displays the Login activity, but if I press the MENU key the Main application menu still shows.

How do I remove the menu from the Login activity?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a result of inheritance? (e.g. `class Login extends Main`).

Comment: that's a smart question. However, here is my class structure: - MyAbstractActivity (base class), LoginActivity extends MyAbstractActivity, MainActivity extends MyAbstractActivity. And I inflate the menu in the MainActivity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooooops, my bad. The inflate menu code was accidentally copied and pasted to Login Activity when I was coping another piece of code :)

Sorry about this
Thanks anyway for the support!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to call startActivity from your MainActivity to go to the Login Activity. Because the Activity chain, would be enough calling finish from your MainActivity.

Comment: I think it's better the way Marco is doing it. Of course, hi will have to finish the Login activity before starting the Main one. Otherwise, the user could press the Back key in the main activity and find out that he is logged out, which is not good.